# Is my Monitor Non-Compatible with HDMI Cables?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have two AOC e2050Swd set up for my computer. I'm trying to set it up so I can switch to a different system on one monitor (be it for gaming or watching a movie off a dvd  player) but it doesn't have an HDMI port. So I got a hdmi-dvi converter plug. When I plug that in it goes from no signal to "Invalid Input."

Is my monitor simply not compatible with the signal coming from an HDMI cable and I need a new monitor?

Comment: is the HDMI port on the other end connected to a PC or something else? Maybe the device dosen't detect/'speak' hdmi

Comment: @JourneymanGeek In this case, it's connected to my PS4.

Comment: hm. http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2339061/hdmi-ps4-dvi-hdtv-sound.html indicates its not the device that's the issue. Does the monitor work off a PC with HDMI our on that cable?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It does. So it's not the HDMI cable, it's the ps4 probably running higher HDCP version than the monitor supports.